# while using pdftables_api , when print(a) it show the output of none

Tags: python, ocr

I am trying to use pdftables_api but got `None` as result

```py
import pdftables_api 
conversion = pdftables_api.Client('my-api-key-here')
a=conversion.csv("IBARAKIKYOKUMI.pdf", "output2.csv")
print(a)
```

Comment: Have you considered using a different library? For what I see on the github project: https://github.com/pdftables is a library last updated jun 2020 with only 57 stars and 1 pull request.

Comment: What did you expect instead? It doesn't return anything, it just writes to the output file, as far as I can tell. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].